# vb.net insert row in datagridview with image

Tags: vb.net

How do you insert a row to a datagrid view if a column is an imagecolumn?

If everything's a text column it's just

```
 DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, "A", "B", "C")
 DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(1, "D", "E", "F")
```

but what if the first column is an imagecolumn and I don't want any image displayed on it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.aspx

> By default, empty cells display a default error graphic. To prevent this graphic from appearing for cell values equal to null or DBNull.Value, set the DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue property of the cell style object returned by the DefaultCellStyle property to null before adding rows to the control. This does not affect the row for new records, however. To prevent the error graphic from appearing in the row for new records when the control AllowUserToAddRows property value is true, you must also either explicitly set the cell value to null in a handler for the control RowsAdded event or set the column CellTemplate property to an instance of a DataGridViewImageCell-derived type with an overridden DefaultNewRowValue property that returns null.

Thus, first you set `DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue` *Nothing*:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Nothing
```

Then you pass *Nothing* as the argument for the image column of `Rows.Insert`:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, Nothing, "B", "C")
```

If your `AllowUserToAddRows` of `DataGridView1` is *True*, follow the steps documented above to prevent the error graphic from appearing in the row for new records.

Answer (score 0):

the code to insert an image column to already designed datagridView with a default image:

```
        Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
        Dim inImg As Image = Image.FromFile("Image Path")
        img.Image = inImg
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(img)
        img.HeaderText = "Image"
        img.Name = "img"
```

Reference : http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_image.htm